# Spring WebClient : Implement Fallback method

Tags: spring, spring-webflux

I want to call my fall-back API when my actual API is taking more than 1 second

```java
@GetMapping("/{id}")
    public String getDetailsById(@PathVariable Long id) {
        var url = getAPIUrl(id);

        var response = webClient.get()
                .uri(url)
                .retrieve()
                .onStatus(HttpStatus::isError,this::myFallBackMethod)
                .bodyToMono(String.class)
                .timeout(Duration.ofSeconds(1))

                .block();


        return response;
    }

   private Mono<? extends Throwable> myFallBackMethod(ClientResponse clientResponse) {
        return Mono.just("");

    }
```

I get two compile exceptions

> Incompatible types

and

> cannot resolve methoe myFallBackMethod

How to handle fall backs and return the String ?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do that my calling the function `onErrorResume`

```java
@GetMapping("/{id}")
    public String getDetailsById(@PathVariable Long id) {
        var url = getAPIUrl(id);

        var response = webClient.get()
                .uri(url)
                .retrieve()
                .bodyToMono(String.class)
                .timeout(Duration.ofSeconds(1))
                .onErrorResume(throwable -> myFallBackMethod(id,throwable))
                .block();


        return response;
    }

    private Mono<? extends String> myFallBackMethod(Long id, Throwable throwable) {
      return Mono.just("test sample");
    }
```